# Refresh data in JTable when using a DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, defaulttablemodel

I have a `JFrame` where I construct a `JTable`.

The `JTable` is made in two steps:

1. I make a function `initTable()` where I make my table
2. I make another function `initDataintoTable()` which ads my data from an arraylist to my table.

Everything works fine until now. The problem comes when I try to update my `JTable`. In fact, I open a `JDialog` and I try to a new item on the list. I get to the point of modifying the `Arraylist` with the new item, but I can't get my table updated after, I don't really know where to put the `fireTableDataChanged()` for example and how to call it when I want it.

In the initDataintoTable I added a TableModelListener to my DefaultTableModel tablemodel.

```
protected void initDataIntoTable() {
    tablemodel.setRowCount(0);

    for (//every item on my list) {
    String[] row = {dataitem, dataitem2};
        tablemodel.addRow(row);
    }

    TableModelListener myjtable_listener = new TableModelListener() {
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                            // I have to write something here to update my table ?
                            // I don't know if it's here where I have to update my table and if it is, how should I call this listener from the place I want to update ?
            tablemodel.fireTableDataChanged(); // ?
        }
    };
    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(jtable_listener);
    //tablemodel.addTableModelListener(myjtable_listener);
    }
}
```

In my jDialog, I have an ActionListener on the Ok button:

```
class OKButton implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Here I manage to get my updated list of objects
            // What should I call here to update my jtable ?    
    }
}                   
okbutton.addActionListener(new OKButton());
```

I already saw a few questions on this website, but nothing I tried actually worked with my program. 
Thank you for your help and sorry for my english.

Comment: From the looks of it, you are using a `DefaultTableModel`, you shouldn't need to trigger any events as the `DefaultTableModel` will do it automatically, the likely issue is the model you are updating is not the model attached to the table or the table you are updating is not the table on the screen...

Comment: What a literally do is create a new object and add it to the list of my objects. I tested with System.out.println() my list at every step and modification I made when I was adding the new object and I see the new one after I add the object. 
What my JTable is doing is reading my list of objects and showing it. I just can't update the jtable with my updated list.

Comment: _" I get to the point of modifying the Arraylist with the new item, but I can't get my table updated after,"_. Don't hold you data in two places. The TableModel is all you need.

Comment: It's funny that you are using the observer as an observable that delegates a fire event, you can have an infinite recursion there..

Comment: @nachokk I deleted the myjtable_listener as DefaultTableModel fires itselfs when updated as I understand. (I mention I'm a beginner in java and these are my first manipulations to make a little game)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never have to call `fireTableDataChanged` method explicitly since it's up to the [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) implementation to notify the ***view*** when data has been changed (insert/update/delete).

In your case calling `tablemodel.addRow(...)` is enough: the table ***model*** will notify the ***view*** that data has changed and this last one will be updated.

```
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
        ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).addRow(...);
        ...
    }
};
```

### Edit

You state in a comment:

> I can't do `jframe.getTable()` without having getTable static, and I
>   can't get `getTable()` static without making table static. After doing
>   this, my program works just like I wanted to.

If you have to add `static` modifier to make it work then you have a design problem. You probably have variables' scope issues in your code. Please see the example below: `InputDialog` is a different class that holds a reference to the table model without any `static` variable.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Demo {

    private void createAndShowGUI() {

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"TimeStamp", "Value"}, 0) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                switch(columnIndex) {
                    case 0: return Date.class;
                    default:  return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
                }
            }
        };

        final JTable table = new JTable(model);

        JButton button = new JButton("Add entry...");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new InputDialog((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class InputDialog {

        private final DefaultTableModel model;

        public InputDialog(DefaultTableModel model) {
            this.model = model;
        }

        public void createAndShowGUI() {

            final JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
            textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{new Date(), textField.getText()});
                    Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent((Component)e.getSource());
                    window.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(window, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                }
            });

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(new JLabel("Please input a value and press ENTER key:"));
            panel.add(textField);

            JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
            dialog.setModal(true);
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.add(panel);
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                
                new Demo().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, because it's in the title :P However my first statement is more generic because it's about the table model implementation (not only about `DefaultTableModel`) @MadProgrammer

Comment: Sorry, may bad, missed the title :P

Comment: No problem, we do that all the time xD @MadProgrammer

Comment: @MadProgrammer how do I call the actual table from my JFrame (or the actual tablemodel) so I could take it's Model with getModel() and add the new Row with addRow() ?
(My thoughts: I made a new fonction getModel in my JFrame which returns my tablemodel and I do it like myjframe.getModel().addRow(), or I do the function getTable, initialize a jtable with my Jtable to have the table.getModel().addRow(). It doesn't work.)

Comment: @user3450862 At the end of the day, you want the model from the `JTable` that is currently on the screen, otherwise nothing will work...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, yes, but doing this:

String[] row = {object.getName(), "Age"};

JTable table = jframe.getTable();  

((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).addRow(row);

I get a big java.lang.NullPointerException error on the second line.

Comment: @user3450862 Then I would surmise that `jframe.getTable()` is returning `null` possible indicating a reference shadowing issue, but without a runnable example to diagnose the issue from, it's all guess work

Comment: I changed some static references for my JTable and DefaultTableModel declarations and function and is working now. Thank you so much for guiding me. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @user3450862 I hope that means you removed some `static` references, `static` is not a solution

Comment: I can't do jframe.getTable() without having getTable static, and I can't get getTable() static without making table static. After doing this, my program works just like I wanted to.